# Deleting a part of string from string when converting using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I would like to know how to delete a part of string from string when converting from one XML to another XML.

For example, say I have the source XML that has:

```
<element id="#yo">
```

however, after the translation I want this to be

```
<element id="yo">
```

Can I do this easily in XSLT? let me know thanks

also, can I do vice versa? yo to #yo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="element[starts-with(@id,'#')]">
<element id="{substring(@id,2)}">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</element>
</xsl:template>
```

and in reverse

```
<xsl:template match="element">
<element id="#{@id}">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have just realised that I can use concat and substring. Anyway thank you very much for your response!